# Disable screen lock on samsung galaxy pocket gt s5300

Tags: lock-screens

i have forgotten the screen lock on my galaxy pocket. Right now my phone its unlock, but i want to disable or change screen lock pin and i cant remember the pin a.set before. Please help how to remove it complete it, I have setted up the screen display up to 30 minutes so the screen doesnt lock.

Comment: You should be able change your PIN (or change the lock mechanism) under `Settings > Security`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to remove the screenlock : [No Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jraf.android.nolock&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5qcmFmLmFuZHJvaWQubm9sb2NrIl0)

If you have forgotten your screenlock, there is an option on the loack screen for it where youc an verify your google ID that was used to setup the phone and your google id password! It will take you to reset from there. Just remember you need internet for this.

UPDATE: I realised it doesnt answer your question on how to disable it!
To disable it you would need to enter current pattern!